# Is it possible to achieve better than logn search performance on this monotonic non-linear trend?

Tags: algorithm, search, big-o

## My Problem

(you can skip this and go to the next section for the actual question. This is just background info for those who really want to know "why the heck are you asking this?")

Imagine an object sliding down a frictionless hill. There are flat areas where acceleration is 0. And the rest of the path has an acceleration greater than 0 up to 9.81 m/s^2. If you know the hill's shape you can plot the maximum acceleration as a function of position down the hill. Let's say you put the same hill on another planet or on the moon to get a different looking acceleration vs position profile. Why? The goal is to choose the correct acceleration such that you reach the bottom of the hill in exactly 10 seconds. Your position change is fixed. Your initial velocity is 0 and your final velocity is irrelevant, as long as you get down the hill in exactly 10 seconds. assume that you will never lose contact with the hill surface.

This means you can plug in acceleration values (changing the planet) and get the position after 10 seconds of downhill travel. When I plot this relationship, I get a monotonically increasing plot (higher accelerations on the x axis lead to higher 10-second position change values on the y axis). However, my hill is VERY complex. I can't just assume that the relationship is cubic or squared. But it IS monotonically increasing.

Here is some sample data with a plot from my algorithm:

```
acc = [
 1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000
 5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000
 8.5000    9.0000    9.5000   10.0000   10.5000   11.0000   11.5000
12.0000   12.5000   13.0000   13.5000   14.0000   14.5000   15.0000
15.5000   16.0000   16.5000   17.0000   17.5000   18.0000   18.5000
]

pos = [
 5.9176    6.5810    6.9784    7.2429    7.4314    7.5725    7.6818
 7.7691    7.8402    7.8992    7.9489    7.9913    8.0279    8.0597
 8.0877    8.1123    8.1342    8.1538    8.1714    8.1872    8.2016
 8.2146    8.2265    8.2374    8.2472    8.2550    8.2617    8.2676
 8.2676    8.2676    8.2676    8.2676    8.2676    8.2676    8.2676
]
```

[image: Position vs Acceleration Example]

Obviously I'm using Matlab, But this is language independent. Please take note that my data is from my current algorithm which is slightly different than the problem which I described above.

## The Problem Generalized

Given a monotonically increasing or decreasing function with a non-linear and non-linearize-able trend, is there a search algorithm similar to an interpolation search (loglogn), or **at least better than binary/gold-section search (logn)** that will find the correct input to achieve the desired output?

My intuition is that there should be something better than logn available since it is monotonic and trend-ish. I know trend-ish isn't a very good word to use but I think it communicates what I'm trying to say.

**NOTES:**

1. It may help to know that a y calculation from x is very expensive computationally

**UPDATE**

I was not able to achieve better than logn performance on *this specific trend* without linearization. While the data is linearizeable by inverting the acceleration value, the Newton-Raphson type approach suggested by @Gassa was not successful due to the computationally expensive/impossible calculation of the derivative of the function.

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question of whether or not it is impossible. It may be possible to find a loglogn search algorithm for monotonic trends with expensive computation times for f and f'. This question would require a mathematical proof. Perhaps it is time to take this question to the Math stack exchange site.

While a deeper question here still needs to be answered, I believe that the contributions of @Penguino 's answer led me to a way of linearizing the data so that I could use an interpolation search. For this reason, his answer has been marked as correct.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth looking into the idea behind [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which I believe converges with speed like log log n in discrete formulation.

Comment: Why not formulate it as nonlinear-optimization-problem and solve it with something like [Brent’s method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq)? It looks, like you want to search on a discrete-grid; but it looks to me, that it would be much more precise using continuous optimization. Depending on the size of your grid (again: i'm assuming you want to check a finite number of candidates) this could be much faster (often quadratic convergence). (Gassa was faster, but describes something similar!)

Comment: I remember Newton-Raphson from a numerical methods class now that you mention it! For every x, a computation of y is very expensive. I should add this to the question. I do not know f'. I suppose I could convert my function to have a root at the desired position change by subtracting it from my result. I'll have to look into this possibility more. I think the complexity of calculating the f' will rule it out though since y calculations are already very expensive.

Comment: @toshiomagic Still, the intuition behind Newton's method may help devise an algorithm here: instead of just comparing `y` as "higher" or "lower", use the actual "differs by" value to make the next guess of `x`.

Comment: See also [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77442/fast-root-finding-for-strictly-decreasing-function) for some ideas, even if these ideas kind of assume, that the calculation of y is cheap. Some remarks: depending on your setting, you could use automatic differentiation to obtain jacobi/hessian matrices and use appropriate methods then. If you don't have gradients, bisection-search should be best. Optimization, when calculation of y is expensive is often called ```black-box optimization```. But this is kind of hard.

Comment: @Gassa Yes that is what I'm going to attempt. It will take some time though. I will come back tomorrow probably and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: @sascha thank you for the brent's method recommendation. It does sound very similar to newton-raphson. I will be investigating it alongside NR. Thank you for the suggestions. Let me know if you guys think of anything else!

Comment: It seems that the newton-raphson fails due to my inability to compute or approximate the derivative of my function.

Comment: I was able to achieve loglogn performance on my trend. But this was only because I was able to linearize the data. This does answer the question about my specific trend, which Penguino helped me with. I will write my own answer. While I was able to get what I needed, I did not get what I THOUGHT I needed, which was a non linear (non interpolation search) loglogn search algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand, you have a function A(x) which is monotonically increasing between two limits x0 and x1, and also greater than zero for all x between those limits. And your object experiences acceleration k.A(x) between x0 and x1, where k is a scaling factor related to the local force of gravity. And you want your object to start at velocity v0=0, at time t0=0, at position x0, and end up at position x1 at time t1 = 10 by appropriate choice of the scaling factor k.

If this is the case, then I believe the time of travel is proportional to 1/sqrt(k). So all you need do is accurately calculate the travel time very accurately *once* for some arbitrary k, and then scale appropriately. For example, if the time of travel with k=1 is T1, then you will get 10 seconds travel time for k=(T1)^2/100.

So the time required is the O(?) required to do a single accurate calculation of travel time (presumably some piece-wise numerical integration would do for that).

Comment: Wow. I just plotted 1/acc vs pos and it is linear. Mind blown. It's not sqrt like you said. But its definitely linear. I need to test this out on other initial conditions for my algorithm to see if it will work. But I think you may have indirectly solved my problem!

Comment: @toshimagic Time of travel is inverse sqrt(k). I made no comment regarding Acc vs position - that can be any arbitrary monotonically increasing (or constant) function and my result will still be true. Time can't be linear with k because, for example, in the simplest case of A(x) = 1 for all x, the position vs time is just X(t) = k.t^2/2, so starting at x=0 at t=0, x=1 at kT^2/2 = 1, so T^2 = 2/k and T = sqrt(2/k).

Comment: For my algorithm, 1/acc is linearly proportional to position change in a fixed time delta. That's all I'm saying.